# Дата в new Date() не совпадает с датой компьютера

Tags: node.js

Дата в new Date() не совпадает с датой компьютера.
Кроме этого setHours(0) устанавливает не нулевое значение часов. Почему так происходит, ошибаюсь я или проблема в коде / настройках node?

Node работает на localhost'е.

В браузере работает как надо.

Прилагаю скриншот[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не совпадает с локальным потому что оно отпечатывается в часовом поясе Зулу - по Гринвичу.

Comment: Здесь обсуждался этот вопрос [How can I set the default timezone in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083410/how-can-i-set-the-default-timezone-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Часовой  пояс. Z - значит <s>Zorro</s> <s>Zulu</s> Zero - время по Гринвичу, нулевой часовой пояс по UTC.

Браузер имеет настройки локали и отображает время соответственно часовому поясу компьютера. У вас часовой пояс +5.

С установкой 0 та же проблема. Устанавливается 0 по вашему часовому поясу, а печатается по Гринвичу. Полночь у Вас это -5 там, то есть 19 прошлого дня.

Если используете это всё для передачи в json - оставьте как есть. Браузер правильно переведет. Если надо отображать время строкой, то лучше прикрутите https://momentjs.com/ или `date_q.toLocaleString()`

Ещё можно установить часовой пояс в node через переменную окружения.

```
TZ='Europe/Moscow' node ...
```

Похоже он уже установился так как `setHour()` локальный.

Comment: Только не Zulu, а Zero :-)

Comment: @PavelMayorov интерпретация Zulu встречается так же часто или даже чаще https://time.is/ru/Z

Comment: Но она, в отличии от Zero, некорректна

Comment: Я бы сказал корректна и общепринята, но не соответствует гражданскому ISO8601 это да.